# Compiling FFMPEG with x265 has ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config

Tags: ffmpeg, pkg-config, android-ffmpeg, libx265

At first, I have a project with ffmpeg build support x264 for android in Mac OS.

Now, I want to add x265 support.

I have compiled the x265 with make & make install like this:

```
[ 81%] Built target x265-static
[100%] Built target cli
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libx265.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/x265.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/x265_config.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/x265.pc
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/bin/x265
```

and then, I run this shell script:

```
make distclean 

NDK_PATH=$NDK_HOME
NDK_ARM_PATH=${NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
NDK_ARM_BIN_PATH=${NDK_PATH}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin

CC=${NDK_ARM_BIN_PATH}/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

chmod +x configure
chmod +x version.sh

if [ $APP_ABI = "armeabi-v7a" ]; then
LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O3 -DANDROID -fpic -I/usr/local/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"
ABLES="--enable-asm --enable-thumb --enable-hwaccels --cpu=armv7-a --enable-neon"
elif [ $APP_ABI = "armeabi" ]; then
LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O3 -DANDROID -fpic -I/usr/local/include"
ABLES="--disable-neon"
fi
echo $LOCAL_CFLAGS
echo $ABLES
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH

echo "开始configure"
./configure \
--disable-yasm \
--disable-debug \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-stripping \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-postproc \
--disable-network \
--enable-pthreads \
--enable-small \
--disable-encoders \
--enable-encoder=libx264 \
--enable-encoder=libfdk_aac \
--enable-libx265 \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
...

echo "开始make"
make -j4

echo "开始install"
sudo make install
```

It results in an error:

```
-O3 -DANDROID -fpic -I/usr/local/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon
--enable-asm --enable-thumb --enable-hwaccels --cpu=armv7-a --enable-neon
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
开始configure
ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config
```

I looked at the config.log:

```
use_pkg_config x265 x265.h x265_api_get
check_pkg_config x265 x265.h x265_api_get
false --exists --print-errors x265
ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config
```

but, the file of x265.pc is existing on the path. Its content is:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: x265
Description: H.265/HEVC video encoder
Version: 0.0
Libs: -L${libdir} -lx265
Libs.private: -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc -ldl -lgcc -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

and the x265.h is in include path too.

I run

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

It also finds x265:

```
TIMWEILIU-MC0:libSrc timweiliu$ pkg-config --list-all
libecpg_compat libecpg_compat - PostgreSQL libecpg_compat library
fdk-aac        Fraunhofer FDK AAC Codec Library - AAC codec library
apr-1          APR - The Apache Portable Runtime library
apr-util-1     APR Utils - Companion library for APR
libpq          libpq - PostgreSQL libpq library
libpcre        libpcre - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 8 bit character support
libpgtypes     libpgtypes - PostgreSQL libpgtypes library
libecpg        libecpg - PostgreSQL libecpg library
x264           x264 - H.264 (MPEG4 AVC) encoder library
x265           x265 - H.265/HEVC video encoder
libpcreposix   libpcreposix - PCREPosix - Posix compatible interface to libpcre
libiodbc       iODBC - iODBC Driver Manager
```

Now, I don’t know why it does not work.
Why does pkg-config still not find the x265?

Comment: I am already set the PATH  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Comment: Hi, @timweiliu did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
--pkg-config-flags="--static"
```

with

```
--pkg-config="pkg-config --static"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue:
The problem is the x265 repo uses git to create versioning. it creates X265_LATEST_TAG variable which is used as a condition to include the x265.pc.

I had shallow cloned the repository so this absolutely not worked.
Recloned, recompiled. All fine x265.pc is installed correctly.